# How do I edit an image node in blender using python

Tags: python, uv, node-editor

In my scene I have an object that's using 4 different materials. Each material has it's own image node that looks like this:

[image: Image Node]

How would I go about selecting a material by name and changing MyImage.png to a string I can input in python? I'm currently using this code to load the scene and render it.

```
def renderImage():
   bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="../scenes/bodyshot.blend")
   scene = bpy.context.scene        
   obj_camera = bpy.context.scene.camera 
   scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
   scene.render.filepath = "renderOutput.png"
   bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = 1)

renderImage()
```

Edit: Solved thanks to lemon.
The code I used to render the image:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("shirt")
node = mat.node_tree.nodes["shirtImageNode"]
image = bpy.data.images.load("myShirtImage.png")
node.image = image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a material by its name:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials[ mat_name ]
```

To get a node in it by its name:

```
node = mat.node_tree.nodes[ node_name ]
```

To get all the image texture nodes in a material:

```
nodes = [n for n in mat.node_tree.nodes if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE']
```

---

For the image part, I presume it is loaded and exist in Blender.

If yes, to get it from its name:

```
image = bpy.data.images[ image_name ]
```

If no, you can load it:

```
bpy.data.images.load( filepath )
```

---

Setting an image in a image texture node:

```
image_node.image = image
```

where 'image_node' is one of the nodes obtained as 'TEX_IMAGE' above.

and where 'image' is the object obtained from bpy.data.images

Comment: I'm getting the error KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "shirt" not found'

Comment: Either use .get(key) to test it or try except. But if you have this error, that means the key does not exist in your collection (I dont' know which one you're talking about)

Comment: I have tried using .get and it's gone through to the next line where I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node_tree'

Comment: Man, that means you're try to get something that is not existing in your context.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code.